# font-size 12px in input(type=text) but actually height is 15px in browser dev tools

Tags: html, css

I set the font-size 12px and reset the original input style,but in dev tools the input own 15px. why this? what else the input contain?

```
<style>
.text-input{
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:0;
}
</style>
<input class='text-input' type='text' value='text'>
```

Comment: It's showing 12px here: http://jsfiddle.net/40xpa9Lj/

Comment: Which dev tools are you using? I know if you go to the computed tab in chrome, it will tell you where each value is generated...

Comment: Check the zoom level

Comment: What about reseting borders and height? 15px height its default for inputs.

Comment: Can you share more HTML and CSS code? Maybe there is a more specific CSS rule that overwrites this line.

Comment: theres probably a parent that is controlling the 15px

Comment: thanks,the reason is that didn't set the height